# Flutter Dio Google News RSS feed return 403

Tags: flutter, rss, dio, google-news

Using flutter web platform I am trying to get google news rss feed from this link and show it as a news page on website.

https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=ev%20charger&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB:en

Here is how i tried with dio

```
 final response = await _dio.request(
    'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=ev%20charger&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB:en',
    options: Options(
      method: 'GET',
    ),
  );

  return RssFeed.parse(response.data);
```

and

```
  final response = await _dio.get(
    'https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=ev%20charger&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB:en',
  );

  return RssFeed.parse(response.data);
```

No mater how i try its giving me 403 and CORS. If you try this link on browser or postman it works fine.
Priority is to fix this 403 error.
I also tried attaching different headers but result is always the same.
I also noted that the result was successful twice yesterday with the same method and then again 403.
Flutter inapp_webview is not an option because google news doesn't allow embeding.

Comment: if google news doesnt allow cors. then parse rss in your own backend.

Comment: thanks @Qori this could be an option.